# Object expected, javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Please check out this code? why do i get object xpected error? Thank you...**

```
 var object_url = "http://test.com/flash/custom-freechat/";
        var param_url = "category=boy&amp;subcategory=18_22&amp;tags=boy,18_22&amp;ismember=false&amp;appletbrand=jasmin&amp;subbrand=livejasmin&amp;size=1&amp;appletcol=&amp;txtcolor1=&amp;txtcolor2=&amp;txtcolor3=&amp;txtcolor4=&amp;txtcolor5=&amp;txtcolor6=&amp;txtcolor7=&amp;txtcolor8=&amp;txtcolor9=&amp;txtcolor10=&amp;membcol=&amp;guestcol=&amp;asc=GGGGGG&amp;lowCamFeed=false&amp;muteAudio=false&amp;as=0111111011110010&amp;ato=0&amp;isproxy=1&amp;sessionid=572e1f4258ca212116c2ea18de9ddee0&amp;appletroot=" + object_url + "&amp;appletlang=appletlang.xml&amp;appletservers=servers069.xml&amp;freeskin=appletskin.swf&amp;appleturls=appleturls020.xml&amp;appletstream=sharevideo_livejasmin009.swf&amp;tipAnim=3.swf&amp;nxt=exit_chat&amp;performerid=TooHotJack&amp;type=40&amp;serverid=inner4q7opo85n9f0d5q7o4psli6e2712msv9&amp;psid=awempire&amp;pstour=t1&amp;psprogram=REVS&amp;pstool=&amp;isad=true&amp;livefeed=livefeed&amp;issb=1&amp;nodeid=HUBUD&amp;memberip=109.71.162.34@583a56ac26afb30b952b3e0ea39bf66f&amp;proxyip=109.71.162.193:8080&amp;";

        function init() {
            document.getElementById('object_container').innerHTML = "<object width=\"710px\" height=\"284px\" codebase=\"http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" id=\"flash\"><param value=\"" + object_url + "memberchat001.swf\" name=\"movie\"><param value=\"high\" name=\"quality\"><param value=\"always\" name=\"AllowScriptAccess\"><param value=\"\" name=\"bgcolor\"><param value=\"" + param_url + "\" name=\"FlashVars\"><embed width=\"710px\" height=\"284px\" flashvars=\"" + param_url + "\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\" quality=\"high\" bgcolor=\"\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" src=\"" + object_url + "memberchat001.swf\"></object>";
        }

        window.onload = init;
```

**I call this script like this: I cannot edit the script cause it's from another server, an affiliate program. I can edit only the way i call it, which is displayed below:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://test.com/fca/scripts.php?size=1&flags=1&appletcol=7A0000&txtcolor1=00CCFF&txtcolor2=FFCC00&txtcolor3=AAAAFF&txtcolor4=FFFFFF&txtcolor5=FF8484&txtcolor6=FFCC00&txtcolor7=FFCC00&txtcolor8=FFFFFF&txtcolor9=FFFFFF&txtcolor10=FFCC00&membcol=A180C5&guestcol=F06724&addcol1=850000&addcol2=7E0101&addcol3=E33335&addcol4=400000&addcol5=C10A09&addcol6=920000&addcol7=900000&psid=.....&psprogram=PPS&pstour=t1&campaign_id=32339&pstool=61_1&muteAudio=1&site=jsm"></script>

**<div id="object_container"></div>**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` does not mean that the DOM is ready on all browsers. As you tagged your question jquery, replace it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#object_container').html('your string to set innerHTML');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that there's no element on the page with the "id" value "object_container".

Comment: Are you *super double sure* that the "id" is correct? You should at least put in an "alert()" call to verify that.

Comment: @webmaster , how come you have php file in src attribute off javacript , is this a good practice

Comment: The javascript is not my code, it's an affiliate code. I just pull it  with that url

Comment: @webmasters, use firebug and check where the error is , switch on the error..on firebug , u can easlily fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is anything blocked by antivirus-software. If I take a short fragment out of the object_url and search for it on google there are a couple of results depending on  malware: [google: /flash/custom-freechat/](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22%2Fflash%2Fcustom-freechat%2F%22)

Answer (score 0):

Is this code on a page with other code on it? The script may be overwriting `window.onload` after another script on your page does, and then another of the other script's event handlers may be failing because the necessary `window.onload` handler did not run. If that is the case, putting this script before the affiliate script would probably fix the page:

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.onload && window.addEventListener('load', window.onload, false);
} else {
    window.onload && window.attachEvent('onload', window.onload);
}
window.onload = null;
```

Another possibility is that the `init` function conflicts in name with another script on the same page. If that's the case, there's no other option than loading the affiliate script in a separate document in an iframe (or fixing the other script that is on the page).

Answer (score -1):

Webmasters ,

How come javascript scr has php

```
src="http://live-cams-1.livejasmin.com/fca/scripts.php?
```

can you fix this first.

and next do a null check on object_container.

Comment: what is wrong with that?  The php script presumably dynamically produces a .js "file".